# Ran a program as root on accident and now my mq-open cmd's fail with Permisson Denied

Tags: linux, mqueue

Ok so I wanted to know where to see the actual message queue files in a linux system? I have a program that was compiled and ran containing message queues but I ran the program as root by accident and now after running as a regular un privileged user it says Permission Denied when the mq_open fails. I have looked at my workspace directories and changed all the program files back to being owned by standard user by how to get the queue reset Im not sure where to look?

Comment: And what does the program do?

Answer (score 0):

Run the daemon via `strace -fF` and check what it accesses. By doing so you'll find out which files/directories it cannot modify and you'll be able to fix the issue.